# Performing transition after tapping to a button of notification

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, appdelegate

I have to following code for displaying a notification if the app is active. I put it in AppDelegate.m

What I want to do is perform a transition (or segue) to a viewcontroller when the user taps to the second button. How can i do this from AppDelegate?

I think i need to set navigationcontroller to appdelegate.. But i couldnt achieve this.

Thanks

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        NSString *cancelTitle = @"Close";
        NSString *showTitle = @"Show";
        //NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Social Dilemma"
                                                            message:@"Next round is ready to play!"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                                  otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}

-(void) alertView: ( UIAlertView *) alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex: ( NSInteger ) buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == 1)
    {
        //check the button index
        //create and display the other alert view (set the tag property here to 2)
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == 2)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can use uinavigationcontroller, this is depend how much view controllers yours app has. In simple way, you can try invoke present modal view controller to app's root controller: 
 1 ) Add to project custom UIViewController (.h, .m, .xib) (Example name: MyViewController)

2 )

```
-(void) alertView: ( UIAlertView *) alertView
    clickedButtonAtIndex: ( NSInteger ) buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == 1)
    {
       //check the button index
       //create and display the other alert view (set the tag property here to 2)
       MyViewController *first = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
       [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
        [first release];
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == 2)
   {
         MyViewController *second = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
       [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
        [second release];
   }
 }
```

For using uinavigation controller, in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: you can programmatically create navigation controller, assign it to root controller and in alert view's method invoke

```
[self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:second (first) animated:YES];
```